# Kendo Grid Column Menu Options Sort, how?

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-ui-grid

I'm looking for a way to order the columns menu options (Columns that I can hide/show) alphabetically meaning If I have 4 columns in the Grid like this:

---

### | ID | Name | Last Name | Assignee |

I'd like the menu that shows when "Columns" it's clicked to show ordered alphabetically instead of following the grid column order, should show like this when ordered:

[x] Assignee 
[x] ID 
[x] Last Name 
[x] Name

Not sure if my explanation of what I'm trying it's clear enough... I was able to do this with AngularJS Kendo UI Grid but with Angular 2+ Kendo Grid I'm not sure how to do it.

NOTE:
In the Jquery Vr. and AngularJS Version the Kendo Grid takes a configuration object and there's an event called columnMenuInit where I can fix the order of the menu without affecting the actual order of the columns in the grid, but with Angular2+ I'm not sure if I have a way to access that event.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/columnmenuinit

Appreciate any help I can get from the community :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the columnMenu.columns.sort configuration ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columnmenu.columns.sort)):

```js
columnMenu: {
  columns: {
    sort: 'asc'
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/upanADuT

Comment: I didn't explain myself well enough it seems, when I talk about sorting I'm talking the columns menu I'm talking about this menu:

See the example then click in the ... of the column "Contact Name" and then click columns 

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/

Comment: @AnthonyGomez - that is what my example sorts. The values under the column menu.